# Reconciling Ephesians 1:22 with 1 Corinthians 15:25—are all enemies under Jesus' feet?

Tags: jesus, contradiction, christology, kingdom-of-god, kingdom

In 1 Corinthians 15:25, Paul speaks as if all enemies will one day be put under Jesus' feet (NKJV):

> For He must reign till He has put all enemies under His feet.

However, Ephesians 1:22-23 gives the impression this already has happened (NKJV, emphasis mine):

> And **He put** all things under His feet, and gave Him to be head over all things to the church, which is His body, the fullness of Him who fills all in all.

Are all things put under Jesus' feet? Is it yet to happen? Are both statements true in their own senses? While similar questions have been asked on this site already, my specific question pertains to the statement that all things have been/will be put under Christ's feet.

Answer (score 4):

This is simply a case of God decreeing things *as done* as if they are already evident. Whether we *see* a thing is irrelevant to whether it IS or not. What God says will be, will be - even if it is not yet. Heb 2:8 echoes this reality.

> For in subjecting all things to him, He left nothing unsubject to him. But at present not yet do we see all things having been subjected to him. Heb 2:8 BLB

1Cor 15:25 alludes to this time to come when the evidence will be apparent.

Eph 1:22-23 is a statement of fact in the heavenly realm where God's will is *done* and *will come to pass*.

Time is not a determining factor - it is merely a delay in *seeing* the evidence of God's plan and purpose unfolding in the precise manner He has designed and decreed.

Comment: Good answer!  +1.

Comment: I have heard this referred to as the "prophetic past tense" - it is so certain it's described as an accomplished fact. Isaiah does this a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Op's question, "Are all things put under Jesus' feet?
Is it yet to happen?"

Quite often God speaks of things as though they were. He  knows the end from the beginning and scripture seems to always tell of things before they happen as if they have happened.

> He calls into existence the things that do not exist.  Romans 4:17

Ephesians 1:22is another case in point.

> 22And God placed all things under his feet

Looking at a few verses before this tell us when the this will take  place.  It will be at dispensation of the fulness of the times, to sum up all things in Christ.

> with regard to the fulfillment of the times [that is, the end of history, the climax of the ages]—to bring all things together in Christ, [both] things in the heavens and things on the earth.  Ephesians 1:10

The other scripture mentioned is:  1 Corinthians 15:25

> For he must reign until he has put all his enemies under his feet.

We can see exactly when this will take place as well from the previous verse:

It will be at the end as well when all dominion authority and power has been annulled.

> the end will come, when he hands over the kingdom to God the Father after he has destroyed all dominion, authority and power. 25For he must reign until he has put all his enemies under his feet.

He has abolished all rule and all authority and power.

Definition of Abolish,  annulled:
◄ 2673. katargeó ►
Strong's Concordance
katargeó: to render inoperative, abolish
Original Word: καταργέω
Part of Speech: Verb

Definition: to render inoperative, abolish
Usage: (a) I make idle (inactive), make of no effect, annul, abolish, bring to naught, (b) I discharge, sever, separate from.

rendering something inert ("completely inoperative"); i.e. being of no effect (totally without force, completely brought down); done away with, cause to cease and therefore abolish; make invalid, abrogate (bring to nought); "to make idle or inactive"

Hebrews  2:8 makes a good conclusion.

> You have put in subjection all things under his feet. For in subjecting all things to him, He left nothing unsubject to him. But at present not yet do we see all things having been subjected to him.

Answer (score 1):

Both have a different context and meaning. Eph passage speaks of his dominion over all things, or everything is under his feet. But the other means the punishment of his enemies in the end under his feet.

> ESV Luke 19:27: “But as for these enemies of mine, who did not want me to reign over them, bring them here and slaughter them before me.’””

See JFB commentary:

Eph 1:22

> And hath put all things under his feet, and gave him to be the head over all things to the church,
>
> Put all things under, х hupetaxen (G5293)] - 'put in subjection under' (Gen 1:28; Psa 8:6; 1Co 15:27). Not only is He infinitely exalted (Eph 1:21), but He has universal dominion. The original grant of it to man is realized for him in Christ.

1Cor 15:25

> For he must reign, till he hath put all enemies under his feet.
>
> Must - because Scripture foretells it.
>
> Till - there be no further need of His mediatorial kingdom, its object having been realized.
>
> Enemies under his feet (Luk 19:27; Eph 1:22).